# How to generate odd numbers based on user input conditions

Tags: java

The application should print the first `n` odd numbers, where `n` is between 1 and 25, starting at `start`. `start` is between 100 and 200 and it says where the odd number sequence should start. If `start` is an even number then the sequence should start at the next odd number.

Here is and example with `n = 4` and `start = 193`:

```
193, 195, 197, 199
```

The application must allow the user to enter values for `n` and `start`. It must then verify that `n` is between 1 and 25 and `start` is between 100 and 200.

My code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
  
    Scanner sc2= new Scanner(System.in);
    int start = sc2.nextInt();
    
    for (int i=start; i=n; i=start+1+=2)
        if ((n>=1) && (n<=25)) {
            System.out.println("Valid Input!");
        }
        else 
            System.out.println ("Invalid Input!!!");
      
    if ((start>=100) && (start<=200)){
        System.out.println ("Valid Input!");      
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Invalid Input!!!");

    if (start%2==0) {
        System.out.println ("Even Number Inputted! Next Odd Number displayed.");
    }       
}
```

It keeps telling me that `int` cannot be converted to `boolean`. I understand what it says just not sure how to rectify it.

Comment: you only need to initialize the Scanner once, then you call scanner.nextInt() or whatever as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `Scanner`. You should perform input validation *before* your display loop. And your `for` loop syntax is incorrect, the second part should resolve to a `boolean` test (not an assignment) and `i=start+1+=2` is just wrong. Fixing it might look something like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;
do {
    System.out.println("Print how many odd numbers (n)? Enter a value between 1 and 25.");
    n = sc.nextInt();
} while (n < 1 || n > 25);
int start;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter starting value? Enter a value between 100 and 200.");
    start = sc.nextInt();
} while (start < 100 || start > 200);
if (start % 2 != 1) {
    System.out.println("Even Number Inputted! Next Odd Number displayed.");
    start++;
}
for (int i = start; i < start + (2 * n); i += 2) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it! Now that I look at it, this syntax does make more sense :) I was thinking of doing the input validation before the display loop but got a bit annoyed when I kept getting the boolean error message haha.

Comment: @Rho With `int i=start; i=n; i=start+1+=2` it's important to note the second term **should** be a `boolean` condition. Instead you have `i=n` which evaluates to `n` (an `int`), **not** a `boolean` condition. `i < start + (2 * n)` is one possible such condition (and what I thought you wanted given your code). You could also do `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { System.out.prinltn(start); start += 2; }`

Answer (score 2):

First, prompt for the values

```
int minN = 1;
int maxN = 25;
int minStart = 100;
int maxStart = 200;

int start = getInput("Please enter starting value: ", minStart, maxStart);
int n = getInput("Please enter number of odd numbers to print: ", minN, maxN);
```

Now compute and print the results for start = 190 and n = 4

```
for (int i = start | 1; i <= maxStart && n-- > 0; i += 2) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

prints

```
191
193
195
197
```

**Explanation**

First, the user is prompted for input using a method.

- `start` - the starting point selected by the user
- `n` - the number of values to generate also selected by the user

Then a loop is used to generate the values. This works by first, ensuring the start is `odd` by setting the low order bit to a 1.  If the value is already odd, this has no effect. The loop begins with the first odd from start and increments by `2`. The loop terminates if either `i` exceeds `maxStart` or `n` reaches `0`.

The prompt method accepts a prompt message that is appropriate for the type of input.  It also accepts a range to provide a helpful reprompt if the choice is out of range.  As long as the user enters out of range values, the method will keep prompting. Otherwise, it returns the accepted value.

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int getInput(String prompt, int min, int max) {
    int value;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if ((value = input.nextInt()) >= min && value <= max) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.printf(
                "Invalid entry, must be between %d and %d inclusive", min, max);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the for loop condition, you must change i=n into i<=n

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time posting so bare with me.

I believe that the reason you are getting `int cannot be converted to boolean` is because in your for loop, the second statement says `i=n`. This statement of the for loop needs to be a logic block.

I am a firm believer in giving resources rather than the answer, so check out this write up done by w3schools (killer resource btw) on for loops in java: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem is for loop at the condition part, `i` cannot be equal `n` like `i=n`. You can change it `i<=n`